# Configure network card without knowing its name

Tags: debian

I have a domestic headless server that boots from (and has the root filesystem in) a removable USB stick. I install it from my laptop (following this [nice checklist](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apds03.html.en)) and edit the configuration files as required. Ideally I'd like to be able to fully configure the system while the USB stick is plugged into my laptop, so that once I plug it into the server, it'll boot straight to multi-user level with network up and SSH daemon running. **My desired network configuration is very simple: it has a single integrated MOBO NIC which I want to configure statically.**

The main problem I've found is that I don't (reliably) know what interface name my NIC will get assigned. Up 'till now blindly using `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` has done the job, however last time I re-installed it switched to the [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) scheme, and I had to lug over the monitor & keyboard to log-in locally and troubleshoot the system.

So how can I avoid myself such pain in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest, practical solution is to revert to classical behavior.

1. In the USB stick's bootloader config (so, in the grub2 config, for example), add the paramater `net.ifnames=0` to the kernel command line.
2. Continue using `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Given the situation you've described and the emphasis you placed on keeping things simple, this seems appropriate. Just note, `ifupdown` may get deprecated and you'll find `/etc/network/interfaces` will stop working in the future if you are too hasty with an update/upgrade.

Comment: I'll do that, if only because it's a really simple setup and I kinda prefer `eth0` over `enp3s1`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're modernist, you can switch to using `systemd-networkd` instead of the usual static configuration method. See `man systemd.network`; the basic idea is removing `/etc/network/interfaces` and creating instead `/etc/systemd/network/static.network` like

```
[Network]
Address=1.2.3.4/26
Gateway=1.2.3.3
```

Don't forget to `systemctl enable systemd-networkd` as well.

Comment: Didn't know about that feature, I'll sure look into it. Many thanks!

Comment: @etherfish: thanks for pointing out the misleading example file name, fixed. Concerning the matching, I really intended to match every network interface. And the `Device=` key isn't even mentioned in my manuals.

Answer (score 0):

The predictable network interface naming scheme is made to solve exactly this problem of getting different names for an interface at different times. This means that with this change your problem should be gone (until the next change of interface naming in systemd )